# How to know if a user that we follow each other (or no) mentioned me in instagram story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, instagram-api

I'm testing the new facebook Instagram graph API to get more info about my business and I want to know via API when someone tagged me in a story.

About getting the comment in posts (or a new post with a mention), I was able to get via webhook and works wonderfully. I want to know how to get story mentioning. There is a way?

Best!

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2019, I do not believe this is possible. I'm back from F8 where I had the chance to pick some Graph API Engineers' brains. I believe if it were possible it would be via the /tags api under the Comments API.  But the documentation currently states that private media is not supported:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/tags

> **Limitations**
>
> Private media will not be returned